# Smooth Zooming out of a High Resolution Photo

Tags: premiere, zoom

I am trying to start zoomed in a high resolution photo (https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/16000x16000q90/924/ky7llJ.png) full of molecules (start with 4x4 mols) then zoom out to the whole picture (consisting of 80x80 mols, 16kx16k pixels).

The problem I am having is that during the zoom out the picture shakes

I've tried frame blending with no avail. Any ideas on how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: weird. Looks like it could be an aliasing thing. Can you use AE?